# Completeness of $\{x^m (1-x)^n\}$ over $L_2(0,1)$?

Tags: functional-analysis

The question can be obviously generalized, as we can easily come up with an arbitrary set of functions $\{f_n(x)\}$ over $(0,1)$.

Is there any theorem which can tell easily a set of basis functions are complete or not?

Answer (score 1):

Work in $[0,1]$ instead (which doesn't matter, as singletons are null), then Bernstein (or Stone-Weierstrass) tells you $\{x^m(1-x)^n\mid (m,n)\in\mathbb{Z}^2, m,n\geq 0\}$ spans a uniformly dense subset of $C[0,1]$.  Hence they are complete set in $L_2[0,1]$.